# How to find the JVM version that ran Apache Tomcat from its logs?

Tags: web-server, tomcat, tomcat6

I have a Tomcat log directory with very many log files in it.

I want to determine which JVM was running this Tomcat. I could not find anything in the logs I `less`ed and I do not even know if it's possible to get this information from the logs.

Does anyone know if this information is available?

Answer (score 2):

## Tomcat 7/8

I see these in `catalina.out` for Tomcat 8; might be a matter of parsing this file for the right strings:

```
12-Mar-2015 11:20:11.411 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /app/java/jdk1.7.0_75/jre
12-Mar-2015 11:20:11.412 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.7.0_75-b13
12-Mar-2015 11:20:11.415 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
```

Background info: The [`VersionLoggerListener`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/startup/VersionLoggerListener.html) is responsible for these lines. It was introduced in the Tomcat 7 API.

## Tomcat 6

**Edited For Tomcat 6**

This information does not appear in `catalina.out`; try the output of `ps -ef | grep tomcat`<sup>1</sup> instead:

```
tomcat   13410     1  0 Apr13 ?        00:16:52 /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/app/tomcat/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/conf/logging.properties ...
```

<sub>[1] This may vary by your setup; you may have to grep for a different user and/or process</sub>

Comment: I could not find it for tomcat 6 , I do not see anything on logs that have relation with a JVM version

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks I have only  log , no access to the machine else I'll run java -version